# Microphone record successfully but not working in other applications on Ubuntu 17.10 with Lenovo 320-15IKB

Tags: 17.10, pulseaudio, lenovo, intel, microphone

I was using Windows and changed to Ubuntu 17.10. I have a problem with the microphone sound. First, my notebook is Lenovo 320-15IKB.

While I execute the command `arecord -f cd -d 10 test.wav` and say "Hello", for example and after `aplay test.wav` I successfully heard my voice. But when using Hangouts, Skype, and others applications, the microphone didn't work.

I'm investigating if the `arecord` and applications (Hangouts, Skype, ...) have the same configuration.

Using the command `arecord -l` I have: 

`**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: Generic Analog [Generic Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0`

And the application I have by default is **Built-in Audio Analog Stereo** and another option is **Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo**. The same choose the two options my microphone in this applications don't work (the microphone have a low quality and my voice is very very low and have a hiss in the sound).

I tried to install Alsamixer v1.1.3 and configure the HDA Intel PCH Card, but I didn't have any success. 
Also I tried installing and choosing the *Profile Configuration* as *Analog Stereo Duplex* and choose port "Internal Microphone" on *Input Devices*, but I didn't have a success.

Only the extra information, while I execute `aplay -l | grep card` I have these results:

`card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: Generic Analog [Generic Analog]
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]`

I believe who would make a conflict with drivers. 
What do you think?

Comment: install pavucontrol `sudo apt install pavucontrol` and use it to manipulate the microphone for your app

Comment: i alredy install pavucontrol and adjusted, but don't resolve my problem.